# Finding orders made within any ISO week of a specific year using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As part of a reporting setup, I have a SQL query fetching the number of orders placed each week:

```
select datepart(isowk, order_date), count(*)
from orders where year(order_date) = @Year
group by datepart(isowk, order_date), year(order_date)
order by 1
```

Note that I am using the new `isowk` format in the `datepart` function call, as business in Denmark typically use ISO week numbers.

Running this query with `@Year = 2010` yields a result set simialar to this:

```
1           5
2           7
3           10
...
53          3
```

You and I both know that 2010 isn't over yet, and certainly there has been no week 53 yet. Actually, there has - the first three days of the year belonged to ISO week 53 of 2009. While it might be possible to explain this to other programmers, the people who are going to read my reports are never going to understand this. Hence, I want to get rid of this week 53, by "moving" the data over to 2009.

How can I rewrite my `WHERE` clause to filter the data set to orders made between monday of week 1 and friday of the last week (52 or 53) in the year defined as `@Year`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at this myself, using the approach described in my comments on [Manfred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434112/finding-orders-made-within-any-iso-week-of-a-specific-year-using-t-sql/4436373#4436373). The idea is to find the first day of the first ISO week of the specified year and the year after, allowing for index-enabled `between` filtering of the input records.

First, I create a function which will find the first day of the first ISO week  in a specific year:

```
create function firstIsoDay(@year int) returns datetime as begin
    declare @first datetime
    select @first = cast(cast(@year as char(4)) as datetime)
    select @first = dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, @first), 0)
    if datepart(isowk, @first) > 1 set @first = @first + 7
    return @first
end
```

*Disclaimer:* This function is untested (having no Sql Server 2008 available at the moment).

The actual data query can then be made using two invocations of this function in a `between` filter:

```
select datepart(isowk, order_date), count(*) from orders
where order_date between firstIsoDay(@Year) and firstIsoDay(@Year + 1)
group by datepart(isowk, order_date), year(order_date)
order by 1
```

Remember that `between` is two-way inclusive. If the values in `order_date` contain truncated dates (no time), `-1` should be added to the end of the `where` clause. In my use case, `order_date` has both date and time, so between two dates at midnight should do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In fact I do not know any programming language which delivers a isoyear ...

```
create function isoyear(@date datetime) returns smallint as begin
declare @isoyear smallint =
    case
    when datepart(isowk, @date) = 1 and month(@date) = 12
    then year(@date)+1
    when datepart(isowk, @date) = 53 and month(@date) = 1
    then year(@date)-1
    else year(@date)
    end;
return @isoyear;
end;
```

Hope we'll get a datepart(isoyear, ...) next time ...

Comment: I believe this would work, if the second `= 12` is changed to `>= 52`. However, I am slightly worried about the performance, as the `isoyear()` function will be executed for *all* rows in the source data (around 5.000.000 in the dataset I am looking at). If we could only find the first and last "isodayofyear", filtering with `between` would yield top performance.

Comment: Actually, my problem can then be reduced to building a function `firstday` returning the date of monday week 1 for any given year. I would then be able to do: `where order_date between firstday(2010) and firstday(2011)`

Comment: The boundaries can be Dez, 27 to Jan, 4. Only these days can be in the "wrong" year.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
set datefirst 1;

declare @Year smallint = 2010;

declare @DayInFirstWeek datetime = cast(@Year as varchar)+'0104';
declare @FirstDayInFirstWeek datetime = 
             @DayInFirstWeek - datepart(dw,@DayInFirstWeek)+1
declare @DayInFirstWeekNextYear datetime = cast(@Year+1 as varchar)+'0104';
declare @LastDayInLastWeek datetime = 
             @DayInFirstWeekNextYear - datepart(dw,@DayInFirstWeekNextYear);

select datepart(isowk, order_date), count(*) 
from orders
where order_date between @FirstDayInFirstWeek and @LastDayInLastWeek
group by datepart(isowk, order_date)
order by 1;
```

If your first day of week isn't Monday it perhaps won't work!

Comment: Seems like we were typing up our answers simultaneously, and both appear to solve the task using a single `between` constraint. I will try out both when I am at a machine with Sql Server 2008. Thanks :)

Comment: A quick row-test including the last 15 years shows that both of our functions for finding first day of first week seems to work. Apparently, mine works with any value of `datefirst` (0 through 7). This make it seem more robust, which is why I am going to accept my own answer. +2 from me for your help, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Do an IF statement - I don't guarantee the SQL server syntax, but:

```
// IF ISO week is 53, return week 1 of next year. 
GROUP BY IF(datepart(isowk, order_date)) = 53,
  CONCAT("1/", year(order_date) + 1),
  CONCAT(datepart(isowk, order_date), "/", year(order_date))
```

Comment: This will remove all instances of week 53, but that is not what I want to do. The stats from 2009 week 53 should be part of 2009 statistics. Also, this does not account for week *52* "overflowing" across new year (like a few weeks from now) or week 1 beginning in December.

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the fundamental answer here:

If you are querying based on ISO weeks, **you must filter based on ISO Year** (and not calendar year)

*How* you add an ISO year column to your data (or where clause) is as others have described.